# Having trouble with AddSingleton and how it actually works?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have the following line in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFirewallPorts>(Configuration.GetSection("FirewallPorts").Get<FirewallPorts>());
```

This reads data from the `FirewallPorts` section of my appsettings.json file and assigns that data to the `FirewallPorts` class.

I understand `AddSingleton` to be:
creates a single instance throughout the application. It creates the instance for the first time and reuses the same object in the all calls.

Now if I directly inject the `FirewallPorts` into a class like this, it works fine.

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    private readonly IFirewallPorts _fireWallPorts;

public SomeClass(IFirewallPorts fireWallPorts)
{
    _fireWallPorts = fireWallPorts;
}
```

But if I do this:

```
FirewallPorts fp = new FirewallPorts();
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(fp);
```

Everything in `fp` is null.

Why would this be and how would I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: So how is `FirewallPorts` implemented? Does the default constructor actually set any of its properties?

Comment: @mm8 FirewallPorts is just a class with properties.  It doesn't do any work.  thanks!

Comment: No wonder all properties are null then. You need to set them somewhere if you initialize the class yourself. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would this be

Most probably because the default constructor of `FirewallPorts` doesn't do any intialization of the fields or properties.

> how would I fix this?

Implement the constructor to actually initialize the object as expected, or set the properties yourself after you have created the instance:

```
FirewallPorts fp = new FirewallPorts() { SomeProperty = "somevalue.." };
```

The `Configuration.GetSection.Get` method does the latter for you behind the scenes, i.e. it creates and instance and set its properties according to what you specified in the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm wondering why the `AddSingleton` works when I use DI but not when I initialize it manually.  thank you

Comment: See my last sentence. It has nothing to do with `AddSingleton` but with `Configuration.GetSection("FirewallPorts").Get<FirewallPorts>()`. Try this for example: `var fp = Configuration.GetSection("FirewallPorts").Get<FirewallPorts>();`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic with Dependency Injection.  When you do:

```
FirewallPorts fp = new FirewallPorts();
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(fp);
```

You are not using any DI implementation.  You're just creating the class with the default properties which in your case is null values.

Lets say for example you're using asp.net. Asp.net is using the DI infrastructure to create instances of your classes in response to http requests.

As an example you could do the same thing in your startup code if you built the service provider:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
   
   services.AddSingleton<IFirewallPorts>(Configuration.GetSection("FirewallPorts").Get<FirewallPorts>());
   
   IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
   
   IFirewallPorts ports = provider.GetRequiredService<IFirewallPorts>();
}
```

Your "ports" instance above would now have valid values. To state this another way, you shouldn't be manually creating IFirewallPorts instances.